# Accessing second element of tuple-key in a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:-

```
Diction = {'stars': {(s4, s3): (2, 3), (s3, s4): (3, 2), (s3, s2): (2, 3), (s2, s3): (3, 2), (s2, s1): (2, 2),(s1, s2): (2, 2), (h1, s1): (0, 1), (s1, h1): (1, 0),(h2, s2): (0, 1), (s2, h2): (1, 0), (h3, s3): (0, 1),(s3, h3): (1, 0), (h4, s4): (0, 1), (s4, h4): (1, 0)}}
```

Now value for key 'stars' is another dictionary. In this dictionary if I know first elements of tuple-key and tuple value (for ex s4 and 2 for first item), Is it possible to access second element of tuple key i.e. s3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how much help this will be, but you could iterate over the `.items()` of your (inner) dictionary, which will give you (key, value) pairs as tuples.

This `search` function is basically just doing that, with inline unpacking:

```
def search(d, sk0, sv0):
    for ((k0, k1), (v0, _)) in d.items():
        if k0 == sk0 and v0 == sv0:
            return k1
```

```
print(search(Diction['stars'], s4, 2))  # -> s3
```

I have no idea what the variables are, so I used `k0`,`k1` for the key components and `v0` for the first value component, but you'd probably want to use something more clear.

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension:

```
>>> [k[1] for k, v in Diction["stars"].items() if k[0]=="s4" and v[0]==2]
['s3']
```